# Software to archive, organize and search for personal documents like invoices, bills, contracts etc

Tags: encryption, search, information-management, archiving

I am looking for a solution to put my scanned / photographed paper documents like invoices, bills, and already digital documents like pdfs, emails etc. int a folder on my local hard disk / NAS and be able to categorize, tag and add a description to the files so I can search for them.

I want to use it just for me (private purpose), so I don't need any teamworking, sharing, document control etc.
Documents should be stored encrypted.
I want to be able to get the stored documents in an easy way if I want or need to switch to another software, ideally just stored in a folder.

Can you recommend me something for my requirements or give me some pointers, All I seem to find are Document Managemen Systems aimed for a corporate environment.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, have a look at [paperless-ng](https://github.com/jonaswinkler/paperless-ng) or [paperless](https://github.com/the-paperless-project/paperless)

They can be used for personal purposes. I think paperless-ng switched off the GnuPG encryption - read the issues queue for more details, but it is available in paperless.

Edit:
A more recent fork is https://github.com/paperless-ngx/paperless-ngx

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [this](https://github.com/uriagassi/paperless.node) nodejs app I wrote, which is intended for local deployment and personal use.

It does not encrypt locally though - the intention is that you will backup using one of the [zero knowledge backup apps](https://www.cbackup.com/articles/zero-knowledge-cloud-storage.html) (I'm using my NAS's [Hyper Backup](https://www.synology.com/en-global/dsm/feature/hyper_backup)).

My requirements are similar to yours, so it might be a good fit! (you can read about my process [here](https://uri.agassi.co/2022/07/23/going-paperless-dedicated-software/).